# Parsing data using PHP, JSON, and SQL

Tags: php, sql, json, parsing

I'm getting several issues in regards to the code I have nearly finished, but for the most part, I have corrected them. I'm down to two notices and two warnings, but the warnings and notices are duplicates of the same problem, so more like one notice and warning left to fix.

Below is the code:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors',1);ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);error_reporting(-1);
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    function saveSubteamData(){
        $con=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db','','');
        $query="SELECT userid FROM subteamfolders WHERE status = ?";
        $query=$con->prepare($query);
        $query->execute(array("Approved"));
        $results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach($results as $user){
            $dom=new DOMDocument();
            $html=file_get_contents('http://example.com/'.$user['userid'].);
            $dom->loadHTML($html);
            $td=$dom->getElementsByTagName('table')->item(6)->getElementsByTagName('tr')->item(1)->getElementsByTagName('td');
            $json=array(
                "id"=>$user['userid'],
                "name"=>$dom->getElementsByTagName('h1')->item(0)->textContent,
                "points"=>$td->item(6)->textContent,
                "ppd"=>$td->item(3)->textContent,
                "wus"=>$td->item(7)->textContent
            );
            $json['date']=date("Y-m-d G:i:s");
            $json=json_encode($json);
            $subteamData=file_put_contents("scripts/subteams.json",$json);
        }
    }
    if(!file_exists('scripts/subteams.json')){
        file_put_contents('scripts/subteams.json', '');
    }
    $subteamData=json_decode(file_get_contents('scripts/subteams.json'));
    if(is_null($subteamData)){
        $subteamData=(object)array();
    }
    if(isset($subteamData->date)){
        $hours=(strtotime(date("Y-m-d G:i:s"))-strtotime($subteamData->date))/3600;
        if($hours>=3){
            saveSubteamData();
        }
    }else{
        saveSubteamData();
    }?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Sub-Team</td>
            <td>Members</td>
            <td>Points</td>
            <td>PPD</td>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach($subteamData->subteams as $subteams){?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $subteams->name;?></td>
                <td><?php echo count($subteamData->subteams);?></td>
                <td><?php echo $subteams->points;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $subteams->ppd;?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php }?>
    </table>
    <br>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <?php foreach($subteamData->subteams as $subteams){?>
        <img src="/images/<?php echo $subteams->name;?>" title="<?php echo $subteams->name;?>" alt="<?php echo $subteams->name;?>">
        <br>
        <br>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Username</td>
                <td>Points</td>
                <td>PPD</td>
                <td>WUs</td>
            </tr>
            <?php foreach($subteams->members as $members){?>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href='http://folding.extremeoverclocking.com/user_summary.php?s=&u=<?php echo $members->id;?>' target='_blank' title='<?php echo $members->name;?>'><?php echo $members->name;?></a></td>
                    <td><?php echo $members->points;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $members->ppd;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $members->wus;?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php }?>
        </table>
    <?php }
?>
```

I get the following:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$subteams
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

These two messages are both on line 56, and then the same messages appear for line 69. Lines 56 and 69:

```
foreach($subteamData->subteams as $subteams){
foreach($subteamData->subteams as $subteams){
```

Doing a print_r with a nonexistent JSON file gives me this:

```
stdClass Object ( )
```

And with an existing file:

```
stdClass Object ( [id] => 649746 [name] => userName [points] => 845,518 [ppd] => 0 [wus] => 74 [date] => 2014-05-11 12:02:50 )
```

So in addition to the messages I'm getting, I'm also only saving one user's details, when there should be many more.

Comment: By default `file_put_contents` overwrites file but not appends data to it.

Comment: I noticed that. My attempt at appending failed, so I'm not quite sure how to properly do so.

Comment: `file_put_contents($filename, $data, FILE_APPEND)`

Comment: Alright, that issue is solved. I still have those other messages, though.

Comment: Well your print_r shows that the message is correct, there is no $subteams property. Are you sure you don't want `foreach($subteamData as $subteams)`?

Comment: Ahh, it does something. The tables are all visible now. Not in the way it should be, though. The folder that's supposed to show the subteams is showing all the users, and the tables below it, which are supposed to show one table per subteam with users of that subteam are all showing errors about non-objects. So something did go right, but in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

*stdClass* can not be handled by foreach. Only Array.

Change the line

```
$subteamData=json_decode(file_get_contents('scripts/subteams.json'));
```

to

```
$subteamData=json_decode(file_get_contents('scripts/subteams.json', TRUE));
```

> mixed json_decode ( string $json [, bool **$assoc** = false [, int $depth
>   = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )
>
> ...
>
> assoc When **TRUE**, returned objects will be converted into associative
>   arrays.

Ref: [PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)